# std::vector subscript out of range while reading a file into the vector of strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io, stdvector, subscript

I am new to c++. I am learning fast, but i dont know much yet.

I cannot see the problem with index in this function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void get_rows(string filepath, vector<string> &rows);

int main() {
     vector<string> rows;
     get_rows("ninja.txt", rows);

     for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
          cout << rows[i] << endl;
     }
}

void get_rows(string filepath, vector<string> &rows) {

     ifstream file;
     file.open(filepath);

     string str;
     int index = 0;

     while (!file.eof()) {

           getline(file, str);
           rows[index] = str;
           index++;
     }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is error message?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but `while(!file.eof())` doesn't do what it appears to do. `eof()` tells you that the last input failed, which isn't true until `getline` fails. However, if `getline` fails, the code happily writes the result of the failed call into `rows`, and only after that does the loop terminate. Instead of `while(!file.eof())` use `while(get line(file, str)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
vector<string> rows;
               ^
             size() is 0
get_rows("ninja.txt", rows);

void get_rows(string filepath, vector<string> &rows) {
           //...
           int index = 0;
           rows[index] = str; // but there is no rows[0] yet
           //...
}
```

you should either use `push_back` to add new elements into `vector` or create a `vector` with specified size at the beginning (if it is known)

```
vector<string> rows(160);
```

which has advantage over the former as you can avoid potential reallocation (which may invalidate pointers to vector elements i.e)

Answer (score 3):

You have constructed an [`std::vector<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) object:

```
vector<string> rows;
```

and then later you are trying to access its elements although there are no elements in this vector yet:

```
rows[index] = str;
```

You should push new elements into the vector using [`push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) method:

```
rows.push_back(str);
```

---

Also note that using `while (!file.eof())` is wrong becuase `getline` might fail inside the loop:

```
 while (!file.eof()) {
       getline(file, str);
       ...
 }
```

Your loop should look the following way:

```
 while (std::getline(file, str)) {
       if (str.empty()) continue;        // we skip empty lines
       rows.push_back(str);              // and push non-empty lines at the end
 }
```

Comment: Oh I see. What I did is a bad habbit from matlab. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you again, i didnt realize how the eof() works, but now when i think about it, it makes sence.